# Apache2 rewrite url

Tags: rest, mod-rewrite, apache2

Im getting way confused about theese apache2 rewrites.

I need to make a REST interface where I use the real URL's of course.
Im testing at localhost atm.

```
http://localhost/ssase12/services/users/
http://localhost/ssase12/services/users
```

should be sent to the

```
http://localhost/index.php?rt=index/users
```

So I need to detect the 3. folder/name and redirect it to the link above - users = $1.

Makes sence?
Im trying to do this with a .htaccess placed in the users folder... can I maybe do this from the services folder? So everything written after

```
http://localhost/ssase12/services/blah(/)
```

would be sent as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the rules in either the document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ssase12/services/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?rt=index/$1 [L]
```

or the ssase12 directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?rt=index/$1 [L]
```

or the services directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?rt=index/$1 [L]
```